# How to open SQL file

Tags: sql

I am trying to open an SQL file, but unfortunately I have some problems. When I try

```
mysql -u -p dbname < dbsource
```

it says

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database

The file also encrypted SHA512 and I'm not sure if that is the case or not. Need help. Thank you

Comment: Look if this solution can help you:
https://askubuntu.com/a/666245/752939

Comment: Are you sure that the database is created?
Can you be more clear with "open a SQL file"? what do you want do exactly? 
If it's a db dump file, you can open it with any text editor. Please clarify your question.

Comment: As Peshmerga says, it is likely that the db does not exist.  Could you try `mysql -u <uid>-p <dbname>` , just to make sure?